# In react-admin, referenceInput makes a lot of calls to api - How to avoid this?

Tags: react-admin

So I notice that `referenceInput` makes multiple calls to the API. I have the same issue as: ["Too many request to API endpoint when using ReferenceInput and ReferenceArrayInput"](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/3108)

I'm not sure if this is something that can be avoided or if there is a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If the underlying input supports 'choices' then its better to create your own component. e.g. I created a custom autocomplete input, you take a cue from here

```
const AutocompleteProjectInput = ({ name, label, dataProvider }) => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);
    const loading = !open && options.length === 0;

    useEffect(() => {
        let active = true;

        if (!loading) {
            return undefined;
        }

        (async () => {
            const { data: projects } = await dataProvider(GET_LIST, 'projects', {});
            if (active) {
                setOptions(projects);
            }
        })();

        return () => {
            active = false;
        };
    }, [loading]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!open) {
            setOptions([]);
        }
    }, [open]);

    return (
        <SelectInput
            source="projectId"
            choices={options}
            optionText="projectName"
            optionValue="id"
            label={label}
        />
    );
};
```